# Create recurring events without showing those in Calendar in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm building a really simple App that needs to update its database following some users choices. Imagine a simple App for personal finances where users define some recurring transactions.

I'm trying to figure out which could be the best way to implement this feature. 
I suppose that working with `EventKit` could be a good solution, but I can't understand if the events that I'm going to add through this framework are at the end also displayed into users calendar (which is a behaviour that I don't want).

So my question is which is in your opinion the best way to perform recurring events for an Application, without let the user know about that? (obviously through the application users can edit/remove/add these events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well [`EventKit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html) is the SDK that allows you to interact with the user calendar, so any thing you add the calendar will be visible in the users calendar.

If you don't want you event to show in the users calendar then don't use `EventKit`. Just store all the event in a local database and use [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to alert the user.

Comment: What if I don't need to alert the user about these changes? I just want that whenever user open the app, right transactions are already been calculated and stored.

Comment: Then you just do that, read your own local database and select the correct transactions and calculate what needs to calculated.

Comment: Ok so this is the only way to perform recurrent tasks, without let the user know about those tasks. I hoped to make this operation easier.

Comment: How can it be easier, you have full control over what is going on.

Comment: Having the full control of whatever system is not easier, is just not opaque, but at the same time we have to write what could be already implemented in another framework. Ok, in this case it's not such a difficult task, but let me say that this is not easier than having something already working :P That said, I suppose that by your answer and comments I get that there is not an automatic way to define recurring task as I need.

Comment: Well let me just say that, some time it requires more effort to make some framework work for you and it would if you just implement it your self. In case of recurring taks, yes a standard calendar will do.